# Collecting values from the upper rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table in sql server and I want to summarize a cell with upper rows in T-Sql like this:

```
 Quantity          Total
-----------------------------
    1                1
    5                6
    12               18
    20               38
```

I use SQL server 2008, How can I achieve this?

Regards, Majid.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a cumulative sum, it would appear.  If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, just do:

```
select quantity, sum(quantity) over (order by quantity)
from table t;
```

Note the `order by quantity`.  You need to specify the ordering for the cumulative sum, typically doing another sum.

In earlier versions, you can do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select quantity,
       (select sum(t2.quantity)
        from table t2
        where t2.quantity <= t.quantity
       ) as total
from table t;
```

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2008

Comment: @MajidHosseini you should have mentioned that right from the beginning. Than Gordon wouldn't have shown you a solution that does not apply to your version.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Actually, I was interrupted before I could finish the answer.  I do wonder why my original answer was downvoted, because it did explicitly state the version issue.  Alas.